# moving a (file | directory) while avoiding filename collisions

Tags: bash, shell-script, mv

I have a bash script that moves files from a number of different locations to a folder named `completed`.

I want to avoid overwriting previous files, so in the case when the name of a file (for example, `Selection Of Recipes.zip`) I want to move is already in `completed`, add a nonce or other string to the filename to differentiate (`Selection of Recipes-???.zip`, where `???` is a random string).

Is this possible with just `mv`, or should I try creating another bash script with arguments that handles that aspect? Does anyone have a bash script that I can pattern my own against?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using GNU `mv` you have the following option.

```
$ mv -b source/* dest/.
```

This switch tells `mv` to push any files that collide in the `dest/.` directory to a backed up version, typically adding a tilde (`~`) to the end of the file, prior to moving files into the directory.

#### Example

Say I have the following sample directories with files.

```
$ mkdir source dest
$ touch source/file{1..3} dest/file{1..5}

$ tree
.
├── dest
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
└── source
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```

Now when we move files from `source` to `dest`:

```
$ mv -b source/* dest/.
$ tree 
.
├── dest
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file1~
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file2~
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file3~
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
└── source

2 directories, 8 files
```

#### Controlling the extension

Again with GNU's version of `mv` you can change the default behavior using the `-S <string>` switch.

```
$ mv -b -S "string" source/* dest/.
```

#### Example

```
$ mv -b -S .old source/* dest/.

$ tree 
.
├── dest
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file1.old
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file2.old
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file3.old
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
└── source

2 directories, 8 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script.  If you call it `move`, you will have to use the command `move file destination`

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
DEST=$2

if `ls ${DEST}/${FILE} > /dev/null`
then
    base=`echo ${FILE} | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
    ext=`echo ${FILE} | sed 's/.*\.\(.*\)/\1'`
    r=$RANDOM
    mv ${FILE} ${DEST}/${base}-${r}.${ext}
else
    mv ${FILE} ${DEST}
fi
```

You probably should add some validation (like making sure that the random numbered file does not exist already) and the fact that the user supplies two arguments.